# Number of masters for particular slave in multi source Replication MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, multi-source-replication

Mysql has launched a new feature that a single slave server has multiple master server in which replication can be handled with the help of flag called channel for each separate master server.

I want to know:

```
What's the max number of master a slave can have ?
Or 
max number of channels a slave can have ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in MySQL 5.7, the maximum number of channels that can be added to one slave in a multi-source replication topology is **256**.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-channels.html